# HtmlUnit - How to get the correct form?

Tags: java

I am trying to login to account.mojang.com/login through HtmlUnit. I couldn't seem to find the form to login so I looped through all forms on the page and if they had a login button, it would preform everything. How can I just get the form that I am looking for?
(Here is the code, it doesn't work though.)

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void nk(){
    String username = Sniper.username;
    String email = Sniper.email;
    String password = Sniper.pass;
    System.out.println("Sniping!");
    final WebClient web = new WebClient();
    try{
        final HtmlPage page1 = web.getPage("https://account.mojang.com/login");
        for(HtmlForm loginForm: page1.getForms()){
            if(loginForm.getInputByName("Log in")!=null){
                final List<HtmlInput> loginButton = loginForm.getInputsByValue("Log in");
                final HtmlTextInput emailEnter = loginForm.getInputByName("E-mail");
                emailEnter.setValueAttribute(email);
                final HtmlTextInput passbutton = loginForm.getInputByName("Password");
                passbutton.setValueAttribute(password);
                final HtmlPage page2 = loginButton.get(0).click();
                System.out.println(page2);
                changeUsername1(page2.getAnchorByText("Change").click(), username, password);
            }}
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            sniped = true;
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void changeUsername1(Page page1,String username, String password){
        final WebClient web = new WebClient();
        try{
            final HtmlPage page = web.getPage(page1.getUrl());
            for(HtmlForm form :page.getForms()){
                if(form.getInputsByValue("Change name")!=null){
                    final List<HtmlInput> button = form.getInputsByValue("Change name");
                    final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("New profile name");
                    textField.setValueAttribute(username);
                    final HtmlTextInput textField1 = form.getInputByName("Password");
                    textField1.setValueAttribute(password);
                    final HtmlPage page2 = button.get(0).click();
                    form.getButtonByName("Yes").click();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sniped = true;
        }
        sniped = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using? Use `Firebug` or one such tool to search for the form. The following is the form on that page - searched with Safari inspect tool.

`<form action="/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="loginForm"><input type="hidden" name="authenticityToken" value="60e3d81d00a7ed6e8cb192c52fcddfb9bdfe322d">`

Comment: I'm using Chrome & testing it now. :) Thanks!

Comment: I used the name you said but I got this error: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[authenticityToken]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:638)
        at me.InfIV.Sniper.Stuff.nk(Stuff.java:38)
        at me.InfIV.Sniper.Sniper.setStuff(Sniper.java:54)
        at me.InfIV.Sniper.Sniper.main(Sniper.java:42) Line 38 is final HtmlForm loginForm = page1.getFormByName("authenticityToken"); I do not know why this is happening

Comment: Use `getElementById('loginForm')` and cast it to `HTMLForm`

Comment: I have another question, is there a way to get a button by id? (within a form)? There isn't a getElementById method in HtmlForm.

Comment: Not sure. But you can get all elements  using `getAll` and search for it.

Comment: hm, is it form.getAll()? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `HTMLElement#getAll` - a form is also a HTMLElement.